# Karate Custom Serialiser for Java Return Value

Tags: karate

Say I have a Java class like this:

```
package com.example;
public class PersonUtil {
    static class Person {
        LocalDate dob;
        String name;
        Person(LocalDate dob, String name) { this.dob = dob; this.name = name;}
    }

    public static Person person() {
        return new Person(LocalDate.now(), "bob");
    }
}
```

and then I have `common.feature` file like this:

```
@ignore
Feature:

Scenario:
    * def personUtil = Java.type('com.example.PersonUtil')
```

and then a `test.feature` file like this:

```
Feature: Create Person

Background:
  * def util = call read('common.feature')
  * print util.personUtil.person();
```

The problem is that the dob field in the feature files looks like the following structure:

```
{"dob": {"year":2019, 
    "month":"MAY", 
    "monthValue":5, 
    "dayOfMonth":1, 
    "leapYear":false, 
    "dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY", 
    "dayOfYear":121, 
    "era": "CE", 
    "chronology": {
        "id":"ISO", 
         "calendarType":"iso8601"
        }}, 
 "name":"bob"}
```

but I would like it to be using a DateFormatter so the output was

```
{"dob": "2019-05-1", "name":"bob"}
```

Is there a way to do this with the Karate without creating another DTO and doing the LocalDate formatting myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Peter Thomas, Thanks that does work but it got me thinking a bit more and what I ended up doing was reusing one of my utils for ObjectMapper to serialise the Object to JSON (and that objectmapper handles all the type conversion). Then I wrap the call to get Java objects with that serialise function and cast the result back to json in the feature file like the following:

Same as before but with new `serialise` helper`:

```
package com.example;
public class PersonUtil {
    static class Person {
        LocalDate dob;
        String name;
        Person(LocalDate dob, String name) { this.dob = dob; this.name = name;}
    }

    public static Person person() {
        return new Person(LocalDate.now(), "bob");
    }

    public static String serialise(Object o) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return ObjectMapperUtils.createObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(o);
    }
}
```

Similar to before but now wrap the call with the `serialise` helper:

```
Feature: Create Person

Background:
  * def util = call read('common.feature')
  * json person = util.personUtil.serialise(util.personUtil.person());
  * print person
```

That way I don't need to do a new mapper for each type of Java object that requires special conversions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try this:

```
* def mapper = function(x){ return { name: x.name, dob: x.dob.toString() } }
* def person = mapper(util.personUtil.person())
* print person
```

From the above it should be easy for you to figure out how to do any kind of conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. See my response below to see what I ended up doing. Btw Karate is awesome and I've managed to get our company to start using it for E2E tests.